# cmake environment error with clion

Tags: cygwin, mingw, cmake

I downloaded `MinGW/cygwin/mingw-w64` not one of them work. I can't find the issue, every time `CMake - Bundled "!Does not work in this environment"`.
I watched youtube for clion-setup more than one. I followed them step by step, same error ??
the issue is whatever Environment I chose non one of them work CMake give me error (`CMake - Bundled "!Does not work in this environment`) . what I know 90% it must detect auto. I delete `mingw/w64/cygwin` & reinstall them(Each one alone),  I did path in system variables, I missed something, I don't know what. And thank you all for your help I appreciate that.

[image: CMake Issue]

I'm using windows 10 pro.

Comment: Add the image not a link to your question. Why do you expect the cmake bundled in clion should work with cygwin or mingw and do you not use the one available in those platform ?

Comment: What are the errors of cmake ?

Answer (score 1):

I find the solution because the `Cygwin / MinGW / MInGW-W64` thay all in the Path . I delete them all except one restart the laptop &  it's work fine :).
P.S. I kept the `MinGW-W64` .

Answer (score 0):

For Cygwin, the configuration works fine with autodetection without any issue.
It also accept the Cygwin `cmake` if chosen (version 3.13.1) instead of the bundled.

[image: clion setup]